# django-allauth how to extend view? Best practice

Tags: django, django-allauth

I'm using allaouth and I want to add my main menu in all the allaouth html templates. My main menu is a model with menu items and I was thinking to add them in account.views as a parameter of render_to_response.

Then I find out that all the views are written as classes and are extending some other classes. I'm not sure what is the best way to edit that kind of setup.

Can someone suggest how to extend account.views?

Answer (score 0):

You can extend django-allauth class based views by your custom classes to add all what you need.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound like you need to change views. If you want to have a menu on every page, then just have allauth extend a page that has menus.

Django allauth extends `account/base.html` which in turn extends `base.html` by default which you could replace (then put that app above allauth in `INSTALLED_APPS`).

If the problem is that you need context data for the menu to render, then I think this is an appropriate use case of [context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#context-processors).